# Узнать передавалось ли поле в JSON (VK)

Tags: php, json, вконтакте

Есть такой JSON (VK Callback):

```
{  
   "type":"message_new",
   "object":{  
      "id":207,
      "date":1496515936,
      "out":0,
      "user_id":xxx,
      "read_state":0,
      "title":" ... ",
      "body":"",
      "attachments":[  
         {  
            "type":"photo",
            "photo":{  
               "id":456239686,
               "album_id":-15,
               "owner_id":xxx,
               "photo_75":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c636428\/v636428215\/518b3\/Z19yBGKd6OY.jpg",
               "photo_130":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c636428\/v636428215\/518b4\/M5v3vOzVBTU.jpg",
               "photo_604":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c636428\/v636428215\/518b5\/GGnhdalq4dk.jpg",
               "photo_807":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c636428\/v636428215\/518b6\/9mb2RLIJ9To.jpg",
               "photo_1280":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c636428\/v636428215\/518b7\/FAnQRoN9TdY.jpg",
               "photo_2560":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c636428\/v636428215\/518b8\/o-Yc5_HCZvE.jpg",
               "width":1600,
               "height":2133,
               "text":"",
               "date":1488713884,
               "access_key":"xxx"
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "group_id":xxx
}
```

Каким способом узнать, было ли передано в сообщении изображение? На ум приходит только проверка вхождения определённой подстроки в строку и регулярные выражения.
Заранее огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (response.object.attachments && response.object.attachments.type == 'photo') {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, кажется получилось проверить, есть прикреплено ли изображение (но только оно одно, что мне и надо)

`if ($a->object->attachments && $a->object->attachments[0]->type == 'photo') {
     echo('with');
 } else {
  echo('without');
 }`

Comment: @Николай а, там массив. тогда, возможно, имеет смысл в цикле прогонять attachments и смотреть, есть ли поле с типом `photo`. А то там же много атачей может прилететь и в индексе `[0]` может оказаться видео например